# Measurable Functions - Constructing Examples

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to determine functions such that:

f is non-measurable but |f| is measurable

f is non-measurable but $f_n$ are measurable

$f_1$ and $f_2$ are not measurable but fg is measurable

These are just a few examples of the types of relationships I am trying to establish.  Basically, for any possible operation I am trying to determine where measurability fails to hold.  Are there any good rules of thumb?

Comment: The pointwise limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable.  So your second one (if I'm reading it correctly) is impossible.

Comment: I could not discern any relations between the $f_n$ and $f$.  You likely surmise what the asker wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $M$ is nonmeasurable set. Then define
$f(x) = 1$ if $x\in M$ and $-1$ otherwise. $f$ is not measurable but $|f|=1$, and all constant functions are measurable.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M$ be any nonmeasurable set. Consider $f=\chi_M$ (the characteristic function of $M$) and $g=1-\chi_M$. These functions are not measurable, but their multiplication $fg$ is measurable, since it is a constant function.